# Reading from hidden Oracle Tables with VBA ADODB

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to read from different Tables on a Oracle Database using VBA and Excel.
Usually when read the tables I run something like:

```
Dim rs As Object
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim query As String: query = "SELECT * FROM OBJ_NAME"
rs.Open query, con
```

However, this does not work for all the tables. Using SQL Developer i usually run at the beginning:

```
exec session#.open_session();
```

After which I can read any table. Is there a way to run this command with an ADODB.Recordset in the beginning too? Just replacing the SQL Query with the command did not work.

Or is there different way to read this 'hidden' Tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
Dim rs As Object
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim query As String: query = "begin session#.open_session; end;"
With rs
        .ActiveConnection = con
        .Open query, con
End With

Set connectToDB = con
```

This should work using VBA. Let me if it worked :)

Comment: Glad I could help you :)